# Are the C++ Qt Headers the same for windows and linux?

Tags: c++, qt, header-files, cross-compiling

I've set up a cross-compile environment with mingw on my ubuntu machine and I'm trying to set it up with Qt.

I've read a couple of blog posts and other reference pages on setting this up, but none of them seem to explain about where to get the Qt headers from. Of the few that do, they all seem to say download the installer for Qt creator for windows, run it in wine, browse to where the header files are and copy them out.

Are these files different from the ones I have already installed? (I Installed the Qt packages from apt-get) I don't see the point in the half a gig download and unpacking time if I already have the files I need.

cheers in advance :)

Comment: In addition to the headers, compiling with Qt also requires the `moc` preprocessor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are the C++ Qt Headers the same for windows and linux?

They're different. During compilation from source on windows platform qt generates at least one platform-specific file, which is not present in original source code distribution archive.

One of such files is qconfig.h (src/corelib/global/qconfig.h), which is indirectly included from QtGlobal and contains certain platform-specific definitions, such as:

```
#define Q_BYTE_ORDER Q_LITTLE_ENDIAN

// Compile time features
#define QT_ARCH_WINDOWS
```

On linux the file will have very different contents.

This file does not exist in source code distribution and is generated during compilation. On linux system this file will have different contents. So no, you can't just use linux headers. YOu *might* be able to manually tweak headers, but it'll be easier to simply grab existing package insted. And, obviously, you'll need libraries (*.dll/*.lib (or *.a)) to link with Qt, and linux libraries won't be suitable for that.

> don't see the point in the half a gig download

Instead of downloading sdk download [libraries](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads) (see bottom of the page). Each package is 200..300 MB, which is less than "half a gig".

Comment: The link to the libraries points me to an executable, but a tar.gz archive is also available containing the source - which should I download?

Comment: @jackweirdy: *.tar.gz is source code. Compiling qt from source takes a LOT of time, and if you're going to cross-compile for windows, compilation might take longer and might be unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

The headers, the `.h` files, define a standard interface with which you interact with Qt on that platform. The platform specific implementation will vary a bit with platform. So the headers will be the same, but the library itself will be different, meaning you'll need to install a Windows version of Qt on the Windows system, but the same code should compile on either of them.

In Ubuntu you'll need `libqt4-dev`.

Comment: I already have that installed; so if i symlink the "include" directories to point to the existing headers, should it compile under mingw?

Comment: Well the problem with that is you'll still need a windows version of QT to make it run... So you'll still need the QT DLLs. Strictly speaking the headers are the same but in order to link you'll probably need the binaries as well.

Comment: Wrong answer. Qt generates platform-specific headers, and while "headers define standard interface", they require platform-specific header with plenty of defines - in order to make QtGlobal work.